# Flash AS3 SoundMixer Sandbox Violation?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an AS3 preloading movie loading in a larger file which uses SoundMixer to control the volume. Everything works great locally and online when both files are on the same server.

When I split the files however, say to have the loader swf on one server and the larger content on another, when I click on the volume button I get this error. (This error actually outputs whilst testing the loader swf, loading the content from an online server.)

```
Security Sandbox Violation
SecurityDomain 'http://www.onlinedomain.com/content.swf' tried to access incompatible context 'file:///LocalDisc/WORK//loader.swf'
SecurityError: Error #2070: Security sandbox violation: caller http://www.onlinedomain.com/content.swf cannot access Stage owned by file:///LocalDisc/WORK//loader.swf.
    at flash.media::SoundMixer$/set soundTransform()
    at content_fla::MainTimeline/stopSound()
    at content_fla::MainTimeline/soundMenuHandler()
```

I have added `crossdomain.xml` files to both servers allowing access.

The functions that handle the sound in my content.swf are:

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;

function soundMenuHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if (sound == "ON") {
        sound_btn.gotoAndStop(3);
        stopSound();
    } else {
        sound_btn.gotoAndStop(1);
        playSound();
    }
}

function playSound():void {
    sound = "ON";
    SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
}

function stopSound():void {
    sound = "OFF";
    SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
}
```

The issue seems to be because of the SoundMixer accessing the `loader.swf`. Has anyone any idea what is going on and how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found!

Although the crossdomain.xml policy file did include this domain (so I'm not sure why it didn't work). I can explicitly give access by adding this code to the loader file.

Security.allowDomain("www.loadeedomain.com");

Answer (score 0):

file:///LocalDisc/WORK//loader.swf sounds like you are testing locally. To test locally you can disable security checks for files or folders at the Flash security manager:

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html#117502

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I was testing locally only to be able to see the output trace in the Flash IDE.

Comment: I was only doing that to see the error output in the Flash IDE. The problem is that when I run the files online, with each file coming from a different server, the content file does load but immediately stops working, because the startSound function is called and the security violation occurs.

Comment: got a link where I can see the error happening and take a look at the crossdomains.xml?

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for taking a look. It's very much appreciated.

Seems to be an issue to do with the SoundMixer.

http://www.infin8design.com/clients/testlocal/
Both loader and loadee files held together on the same server. The sound toggle button works.

http://www.infin8design.com/clients/testremote/
Loader on one server and loadee on another. The sound toggle button doesn't work.

If I use this line of code when using 2 remote servers the loadee freezes. 

SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);

Files are here.

http://www.infin8design.com/clients/sound.zip

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I downloaded your files and did a quick test. Your loader.swf on infin8design loads the loadee.swf file from www.crooks.co.uk, so I checked for a crossdomain.xml on that domain: http://www.crooks.co.uk/crossdomain.xml. This leads me to a 404. So I checked if you accidently placed the crossdomains on the infin8design server and you did. So to fix your issues you need to add your crossdomains file to crooks.co.uk root and allow access to the file from infin8design.com.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your embed code you have cross domain issues 
Also make sure your crossdomain.xml is up to par and being delivered

```
allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
allownetworking = "all";
```